# send session data from ios device, Is applicationDidEnterBackground always finish the task

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, performance, afnetworking

I'v developed an SDK for all of my applications to use, and I'm having a bit of problem.

I'm using AFNetworking and FMDB, together and I'm calling a method in `applicationDidEnterBackground` 
to send the data gathered in the current session, but it seem that the data doesn't come to the server from time to time, unless i relaunch the application from background.

I'm testing from my iphone 6 and nothing is wrong, even with edge and very bad connection the data arrives to the server no matter what but in my other devices, like iphone 4s and iphone5, it doesn't always arrive when i left the application with simple click of home button.The weird part is, when i relaunch the application the data immediately arrives.

Is it a hardware problem that my old devices isnt fast enough?

I dont think thats the problem, when i use the simulator it works without a problem, the data reaches everytime.

so any idea?

Or any suggestions of where to call this method?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because more or less the simulator/iPhone 6 is faster than your other devices. Developers have about 5 seconds before the application exits the applicationDidEnterBackground method. According to the documentation on UIApplicationDelegate, Apple recommends if you need more time to call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler in your applicationDidEnterBackground method where you can pass a task to be performed with a handler.
Sources:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground: